# How do SQL injections conceptually work? (brief)

Tags: php, sql, security, scripting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)
>   [XKCD SQL injection - please explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

I own a company and am wishing to know the runabouts of PHP while I am hiring for people to maintain and extend code for its websites, I was looing up on security on SQL injections and do not quite understand how these codes can affect the SQL database as they are in contained strings to the query.

How may one show the security flaw, so that I can see for myself what is happening?

Comment: Read this https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_injection and come back with any specific problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) also, use [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection) before asking, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although much of this can be explained online, I have a feeling to explain this in a bit more detail.

If you can visualise what the string will become, you will understand the underlying risks of the script you are writing, in that it will become something else before it is actually ran.

A trivial malicious example:

```
$fromtheuser = "foo'; DROP TABLE affiliates; --";
$q = "SELECT id FROM affiliates WHERE website = '$fromtheuser'";
```

Can you explain what this will become? The developer couldn't.

```
"SELECT id FROM affiliates WHERE website = 'foo'; DROP TABLE affiliates; --'"
```

The key portions of this vector being `';` to end the SQL string primitive, and `--'` to comment out the pushed quote.

What you would be looking for in the code written, is proper sanitization and filtering of the data before it is even placed in to the query. One important tool to help secure this front is some form of prepared query, in such you can bind the parameters to the query so that there is nothing to manipulate.

We can achieve this with prepared statements in either MySQLi (improved) or my personal favourite PDO. A quick rundown of what they look like.

mysql_real_escape_string (can handle encoding and quotes)

```
<?php
$clean = mysql_real_escape_string($q)
```

MySQLi:

```
<?php
$clean = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM affiliates WHERE website = ?");
$clean->bind_param('s', $website); //'s' for 'string'
```

PDO:

```
<?php
$clean = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM affiliates WHERE website = ?");
$clean->bindParam(1, $website); //you can use :site rather than ? and 1
```

Comment: IMO it's much cleaner to pass a params array to PDO's `execute()` method instead of binding params with separate function calls.

Comment: (Through, chriso's example _is_ better)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Look what happens when we set the `$username` variable to something nasty:

```
$username = "' OR 1";
```

The query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '' OR 1
```

An attacker can use improperly escaped variables to inject SQL into your query, effectively bypassing any (poor) security measure you have in place.

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that there are tools through which you can test whether your site is susceptible to injection attacks.

Take a look at

http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'll take a look at this, could be for a great learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

The danger coming from the fact, that SQL query being **a program**.
So, malicious code can be injected in place of some operator.

1. string being delimited by quotes. if a delimiter inside of a string weren't escaped, it will actually close string statement and the rest going to be malicious code.
2. not only strings being dynamic. No delimiter will protect `LIMIT $amount` if $amount will contain malicious code, as well as `ORDER BY $order`.

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting stuff!